How can I find groups in a SQL data set?
I have a SQL table with two columns like this with about 130k rows. (9k unique users, 7500 unique skills)



User
Skill




A
1


A
2


B
3


C
1



I'm trying to understand (and possibly visualize) the number of users who share the same skills sets. I don't know which skills overlap today.
I want some output of Group A {Skills: 1 & 2 & 7} has 10 people,
Group B {Skills: 10 & 95} has 19 people, etc...
Thanks for your help.

A [mcve] is expected to include both sample table data and the expected result (matching the given sample data). Also show us your current query attempt, and add a tag for the dbms used.

Do you mean exactly the same skillset or overlapping skillsets? If one user had skills 1,2,3 and another had skills 2,3,4 then would they not be a match at all or would you want them to be shown as a match for 2,3?

which RDBMS are you using? MySQL,SQL Server,postgresql,..... . tag it correctly

Your sample data is too poor for this question. Please provide more data in the example and the desired result. With your data, skils set (1,2)-count=1(user A). Skils set(1) count=1 (user C) or count=2 (userc A,C)? And skils set(2)-count=0 or count=1 (user A)?

First, you need to group the users by their skill sets.
assuming you're using MySQL, it's something like this:
SELECT 
    User,
    group_concat(Skill ORDER BY Skill, ',') AS Skills
FROM 
    your_table
GROUP BY 
    User;

Next, you can group by skills using the first selection as a common table expression and count the users in each group:
WITH UserSkills AS (
    SELECT 
        User,
        group_concat(Skill ORDER BY Skill, ',') AS Skills
    FROM 
        your_table
    GROUP BY 
        User
)
SELECT 
    Skills,
    COUNT(User) AS NumberOfUsers
FROM 
    UserSkills
GROUP BY 
    Skills
ORDER BY 
    NumberOfUsers DESC;

If you're not using MySQL, you have to find the corresponding function for group_concat (e.g. string_agg in PostgreSQL).
